# Android Download Manager query is downloading

Tags: android, download

How can i check wther the file is downloading or not i have this code :-

```
   DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(uri));
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
            refrence = downloadManager.enqueue(request);
```

i need to query the download manager by the "refrence" ?

Comment: A better way to do that is display progress bar along with downloading file.
In order to achieve this you can get the file size and then use formula to calculate percentage of file being downloaded.
Follow this link: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/04/android-downloading-file-by-showing-progress-bar/
I hope you'll find solution for your question

Comment: i dont need to display progress bar ,, this should be a background downloading ,,but for time consuming i jsut use the download manager insted of making a service all i need is to check whether the file is downloading or not so the user can not click download while the file is downloading or download completed

Comment: OK, in that case you can just pick up the logic how they are calculating the completion of file download, well let me do that for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use query() to inquire about downloads. When you call enqueue(), the return value is an ID for the download. You can query by status as well:

```
Cursor c = downloadManager.query(new DownloadManager.Query()
        .setFilterByStatus(DownloadManager.STATUS_PAUSED
                | DownloadManager.STATUS_PENDING
                | DownloadManager.STATUS_RUNNING));
To be notified when a download is finished, register a BroadcastReceiver for ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE:

BroadcastReceiver onComplete = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // do something
    }
};

registerReceiver(onComplete, new IntentFilter(
        DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
```

Note that you should also listen for the ACTION_NOTIFICATION_CLICKED broadcast to know when a user has clicked the notification for a running download.

Comment: can you make a full example ,, so this can be a full answer ?

Answer (score -2):

Try this piece of code:

```
   protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
            int count;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
                URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
                conection.connect();
                // getting file length
                int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

                // input stream to read file - with 8k buffer
                InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);

                // Output stream to write file
                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/downloadedfile.jpg");

                byte data[] = new byte[1024];

                long total = 0;

                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;

                    // writing data to file
                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                }
                //here you can use a flag to notify the 
                //completion of download.
                // flushing output
                output.flush();

                // closing streams
                output.close();
                input.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
        }

        return null;
    }
```